# A property's type of instance is the constructor of the instance itself, typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm doing BinaryTree stuff with Typescript, so I have something like below:

```
class BinaryTreeNode {
    left: BinaryTreeNode;
    right: BinaryTreeNode;
    parent: BinaryTreeNode;
}

class BinarySearchNode extends BinaryTreeNode {
    left: BinarySearchNode; //I have to rewrite those property types
}
```

So is it possible to refer a property's type of instance to the constructor of the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your actual code, you might be looking for the [polymorphic `this` type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), which is the type that `this` will have inside the actual instance of the class, even in subclasses:

```
class BinaryTreeNode {
  left: this;
  right: this;
  parent: this;  
}
```

(Aside: Note that the above, as well as your original example code, will have compiler errors if you use the `--strict` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).  You are not initializing the class properties, so at runtime I'd expect some errors dereferencing `undefined`.  The root tree node probably has no parent and leaves have no children so maybe you want the props to be optional.  But that's outside the scope of the question.)

Then your subclasses don't require any special treatment to behave the way you want:

```
class BinarySearchNode extends BinaryTreeNode {
  someProp = "okay"; // stucturally identical classes are indistinguishable   
}
```

(Aside: I added a property to the subclass to distinguish it structurally from its parent.  TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal.  Two types with the same structure but different names are actually the same type.  [This can cause surprising results](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) so even in example code it's a good idea to avoid having any empty class definitions.)

Let's test it out:

```
const btn = new BinaryTreeNode().left;
// const btn: BinaryTreeNode

const bsn = new BinarySearchNode().left;
// const bsn: BinarySearchNode
```

You can see that the types of `btn` and `bsn` are automatically `BinaryTreeNode` and `BinarySearchNode` respectively.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?strictPropertyInitialization=false&experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/PTAEBUFcCcDtQPYDMmgLRoM4BdoEsBjbABWgQAcBTabATwElY9s8BDAGzwC9WWF4kCaKGwALPJhEJQBBAFtyedpVAB3ZqNCxp1MtEwAoEKABClbNmpqEkdgBNQAIxXZpAK0g5QrIpA7taUDlWAGsVVhl2VkxJdTFQcjIqYTwmFg5uXjx+IzAhINCXURVEimoWSkkKPlgOABo1cQJNYLDJOSEVTEpYbtBBYQjcShUDAiiY01TWaFpwaBGAOQQ7FQBvA1BQZSRsAC4RcUwAbk3QfABzUX3DiVOt8hmem7E7rYMAXwMxickTadmAGVKDNmstVqBKAAPSywOx-AFzBaUcHrM6YeSUUgUUAAXlAACIECFWLQCcdQMYcJBfNB-IE8KtYCwCBxItFupInqBUnYJCxYBdIBJRKxHMotqBPt9ZL1sE5sPB8bBKKoprVZvMlitKAAKACUADodthTsZZV5HIqDv8NUjtasZfxLZglVpVeqZrRgaDRKiDcbKLszWALfLHK6bYifdAwTrvkA)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
class Tree<T> {
  left: Tree<T>;
  right: Tree<T>;
  parent: Tree<T>
}

class BinaryNode {
    // node data
}

class BinaryTree extends Tree<BinaryNode> {

}

let tree = new BinaryTree();
```

I'm not sure if you want to seperate tree from node, it depends which information are you going to store in those objects.

If you want "same" implementation as yours, you could do:

```
class TreeNode<T extends TreeNode<T>> {
  left: T;
  right: T;
  parent: T
}

class BinaryTree extends TreeNode<BinaryTree> {

}

let tree = new BinaryTree();
```